# CakePHP: How to read a Javascript cookie?

Tags: cakephp, cookies

First, I create a cookie using Javascript function as you can see in the following code:

```
function SetCookie(cookieName,cookieValue,nDays) {
     var today = new Date();
     var expire = new Date();
     if (nDays==null || nDays==0) nDays=1;
     expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*nDays);
     document.cookie = cookieName+"="+escape(cookieValue)+ ";expires="+expire.toGMTString();
}

SetCookie('MyCookie','MyValue',7);
```

Then, I try to read the value using CakePHP.

```
        <?php 
        $cookie = $this->Cookie->read('MyCookie');
        if ( $cookie == '' ){
            echo "Cookie not set";
        } else { 
        echo "Value: ".$cookie;
    }


?>
```

The result shows that the cookie has not been set. But the result is different when read using regular Javascript function.

How is the correct way so that the cookie created by Javascript can also be read by CakePHP?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're setting the domain in javascript.

Try something like:

```
document.cookie = cookieName+"="+escape(cookieValue)+ ";expires="+expire.toGMTString() 
    + "; path=/; domain=.example.com";
```

Comment: I'm assuming that you replaced example.com with your domain?  :-)  
Have you tried using something like the "Web Developer" extension on chrome to view the cookie details?  Can you post what you find so we can make sure that javascript is setting it correctly?

Comment: And what about if you try just regular PHP?  echo $_COOKIE["MyCookie"];

Comment: No, I've never used that. It looks like CakePHP encrypt any created cookies by default(using $this->Cookie->write), so the mechanism of cookie reading by CakePHP may also be different (I don't know for sure). I think, if the cookie is created using Javascript, it's better to get the cookie's value using javascript also.:)

Answer (score 0):

I would write and read the cookie using the same component, otherwise you will get crazy with the reverse engineering.

So I would use

```
$this->Cookie->write('MyCookie', array('MyValue'=>'7'));
```

As specified in [CakePHP documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1282/Using-the-Component)

I hope it helps.

Comment: I agree. I think it's better to put a Javascript inline code to get cookie's value in my CakePHP view (.ctp) file. In some cases, the application process requires the cookie may should be created in client-side.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same problem, and finally find solution for this problem , 
Try this :->

```
SetCookie('CakeCookie["MyCookie"]','MyValue',7);
```

Now you can read MyCookie in your controller like

```
$this->Cookie->read('MyCookie');
```